# How to get name of currently running test in spock?

Tags: spock

In JUnit 3, I could get the name of the currently running test like this:

```
public class MyTest extends TestCase {
    public void testSomething() {
        assertThat(getName(), is("testSomething"));
    }
}
```

How do I do this in spock?  I would like to use the test name as a key in a shared resource so that tests don't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One solution is to leverage JUnit's TestName rule:

```
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.rules.TestName

class MySpec extends Specification {
    @Rule TestName name = new TestName()

    def "some test"() {
        expect: name.methodName == "some test"
    }
}
```

This requires JUnit 4.7 or higher.

Comment: thanks it worked for me where we have special requirement

Comment: is there some way to get the name from the script set-up `def setup` and after `def cleanup`?

Answer (score 17):

For spock 1.0-groovy-2.4 you can try :

```
def "Simple test"() {

    expect:
    specificationContext.currentIteration.name == "Simple test"
}
```

Comment: Better yet: specificationContext.currentIteration.displayName