# Is it possible to log spock feature method names and clause labels?

Tags: spock, geb

I'd like to be able to log the spock feature names and clause labels when running some automated tests. This would help with debugging test issues when using a headless browser for automation, specifically phantomjs. Reason being, phantomjs does not always behave the same way as when using the chrome WebDriver. It would also be nice to have if this is even possible.

```
def "Login logout test"(){
    given: "Go to login page"
        ...

    when: "Submit username and password"
        ...
    then: "Dashboard page displayed"
        ...

    when: "logout"
        ...
    then: "Returned to login page"
        ...
}
```

For example, It would be cool if I could get the above sample spock feature method to log the labels like this.

```
Login logout test
Go to login page
Submit username and password
logout
Returned to login page
```

Answer (score 8):

**Step1:**  Create a Your own spock extension Class

```
package com.example.spock.exetension;
public class MySpockExtension implements IGlobalExtension {
    @Override
    public void start() {
    }

    @Override
    public void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        spec.addListener(new MyCustomSpockRunListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {

    }
}
```

**Step2:** Create a RunListener that can listen to a spock run

```
package com.example.spock.exetension;
public class MyCustomSpockRunListener extends AbstractRunListener {

    private boolean specFailed;
    private boolean featureFailed;
       @Override
    public void beforeSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        specFailed = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeFeature(FeatureInfo feature) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        featureFailed = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {

    }
    @Override
    public void afterIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterFeature(FeatureInfo feature) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for ( BlockInfo block : feature.getBlocks() ) {
            System.out.println(block.getKind().name() + " : " + block.getTexts() ); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterSpec(SpecInfo spec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(spec.getName() + " : STATUS : " + specFailed != null ? "failure":"success");

    }
    @Override
    public void error(ErrorInfo error) {
        specFailed = true;
        FeatureInfo feature = error.getMethod().getFeature();
        if (feature != null) {
            featureFailed = true;
            System.out.println(error.getMethod().getName() + " : " + error.getException());
        }else {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void specSkipped(SpecInfo spec) {
    }
    @Override
    public void featureSkipped(FeatureInfo feature) {
    }
}
```

**Step3:** Register your new Spock extension

- In your classpath or resource path create a below folder structure `META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension`
- Have this as the content of file `com.example.spock.exetension.MySpockExtension`

**Step4:** Run your spock test and you should see output  something like this.

```
given: "Go to login page"
when: "Submit username and password"
then: "Dashboard page displayed"
when: "logout"
then: "Returned to login page"
Login logout test : STATUS : success
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. What  do I need to import to use 'ETESpockRunListener.class'?

Comment: That statement can be removed. Should still work as intended. I edited answer to remove that statement and remove any confusion

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit advanced for me. Do I add these classes to the spock jar or can I keep them inside my project?

Comment: You can keep them in your project. Create these along with your test cases source code.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of every feature method by following :

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.rules.TestName
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class MySpec extends Specification{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class)
    @Rule TestName testName = new TestName()

    void setup(){
       def featureMethodName = testName.methodName
       logger.info("feature method : " + featureMethodName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PiggyBacking on @Raghu Kirans answer, I had to do a little bit more to get this to run the way that I wanted with Data Driven tests.  In the BeforeIteration method of your RunListener I did the following:

```
@Override
public void beforeIteration(IterationInfo iteration) {
    Optional.of(iteration)
            .map(feature -> iteration.getFeature())
            .map(FeatureInfo::getBlocks)
            .ifPresent( blocks -> blocks.forEach(
                    blockInfo -> log.info(blockInfo.getKind().name() + " : " + blockInfo.getTexts())));
}
```

This simply prints out everything prior to each iteration.  Also note that  getKind().name() on the BlockInfo object does not print out the given, when, then of the spock block in our test but instead prints out SETUP, WHEN, THEN and WHERE instead.  getTexts() will print out the combined texts of the block.

Example:

given: "I wake up"
and: "I drink a cup of coffee"

Will be displayed as

SETUP : ["I wake up", "I drink a cup of coffee"]

Answer (score 1):

After continuously searching I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365491/how-to-get-name-of-currently-running-test-in-spock) for getting the test name. But can't seem to find anything on the 'when' and 'then' labels. This is okay for now.

```
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.rules.TestName

class MySpec extends Specification {
 @Rule TestName name = new TestName()

 def "some test"() {
    expect: name.methodName == "some test"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [Spock Reports Extension](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports)

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for. Delivers a readable report leveraging all defined methods labels (Given, when, then etc.). Only needs to be added to the dependencies and automatically outputs a report to the 'build' directory.